# What is best suited for writing a native library once and use it across multiple languages with language bindings?

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform, native-code, language-binding

What language, C or C++, is best suited for writing a native library once and using it in different languages with language bindings (for example, using JNI or Ruby's C extensions), and why?

Comment: The language you know best is probably most suitable.  (I'm trying hard to suppress my instinct to write "X is not suitable for anything, so clearly Y is the most suited for this particular task."  Undoubtedly, the value of X and Y will depend on the developer.)

Comment: C is the universal glue language.  C++ universally is not, exceptions and object layout are implementation details that don't cross interop boundaries well at all.

Comment: Beware however of memory management and garbage collection issues. If your library is to be used by some language implementation with a precise garbage collector, you need to design it very carefully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C, because

1. a program written in C++ can use a C library, the other way around is a whole lot trickier - any construct available in C++ but not in C cannot be exported to a C program, which risks to make your export complicated.
2. A C library will have less dependencies.  C++ libraries will quite often depend on libstdc++, which is that big that for example on embedded systems or more generally on systems low on resources it won't always be available.

Comment: Also, the ABI of C++ has changed quite a bit among versions of GCC, and I'm sure that the one of clang is different. The C ABI is much more stable.

Comment: 1. The reason why its "tricky" is name mangling from the C++ compiler.  This varies from vendor to vendor.

Comment: @JoshPetitt that is indeed one extra layer of trickiness (and forces you to declare them `extern "C"`) but IMO the fact that for example a function expecting or returning classes cannot be exported is a much bigger problem.  Avoiding the mangling in itself is annoying and leads to mechanical, repetitive extra work, not being able to "talk" to the host program without dumbing down your external interfaces may impact the design of the library.

Comment: @fvu: Using pointers to incomplete structs in the interface, and casting them to the appropriate class pointer type into the library is not very difficult and allows you to send and receive C++ objects from a C user. It also helps to keep the interface and the internals separated.

Answer (score 5):

You can write your library in C++ if you like as long as you provide extern "C" bindings/exports to it so the other runtimes can use it.

Comment: @rodrigo, a quick look at ldd(1)'s output will show C++ runtime, unless the library's creator writes in a crippled subset of C++. Won't happen.

Comment: Also just looking at the process's RSS... ;-)

Comment: @rodrigo waa haa haa! (evil laugh) :-)